# SQL оптимальный запрос

Tags: sql, запрос, sql-server

Здравствуйте! Есть такая база данных:

[image]

И есть такое задание:

Вывести следующие поля «Имя покупателя» (Buyers.Name), «Номер заказа» (Orders.Id), «Название книги» (Books.Name) только для тех заказов, в которых количество книг меньше трёх

Я решил задачу так:

```
SELECT b.Name, O.OrderId, bk.Name
FROM Orders O 
JOIN Buyers b ON b.Id = O.BuyerId
JOIN  BooksInOrder bo ON bo.OrderId = O.OrderId
JOIN Books bk ON bk.Id = bo.BookId
WHERE O.OrderId IN   
(
    SELECT OrderId
    FROM BooksInOrder 
    GROUP BY ORDERID
    HAVING COUNT(*) < 3
)
```

Но хотел бы узнать, можно ли написать запрос более оптимально (в первую очередь с точки зрения производительности)? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: План надо смотреть. А так я вижу, у вас double scan таблички BooksInOrder. Если версия SQL SERVER > 2000, можно и без группировки сделать с помощью WINDOW FUNCTION.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я бы посоветовал переписать IN на JOIN